# _ngcontent-c0 being added to a css rule automatically

Tags: css, angular

I was following a drag and drop example in (you can find it here: `https://stackblitz.com/edit/draggable-part-6`)
After implementing the code I tried to move the "box" into a component.

```
<div class="box" appDroppable >
  MyBox
  <div class="box box-helper" *appDraggableHelper>MyBox</div>
</div>
```

And I noticed it doesn't render correctly. Looking at the chrome dev console I notices that when the element renders outside the box it has the following rule:

[image]

When inside the component, it renders the following way:

[image]

summary, the "_ngcontent-c0" attribute in not in the html and consequently the rule doesn't apply anymore.

the scss is defined the following way and does not contain any _ngcontent-c0

```
.box {
  background: #BADA55;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  display: inline-block;

  &.dragging {
    background: coral;
  }
}
```

the question is, why is the _ngcontent-c0 being added to the rule dynamically?

Comment: I just got wrecked by a web site (freelancer.com) which had inserted attributes like `_ngcontent-webapp-c535` and `nghost-webapp-c36`  , was wondering why these valueless attributes were there at all. The page had gone white and so I was looking for anything suspicious in the HTML that might be doing it, and those attribuites are about as suspicious as they get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because Angular hides these classes and limits them to just the component these classes are written for. It's called ViewEcapsulation in Angular.

From [Angular's Documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/Component#encapsulation):

An encapsulation policy for the template and CSS styles. One of:

- ViewEncapsulation.Native: Use shadow roots. This works only if
  natively available on the platform.
- ViewEncapsulation.Emulated: Use
  shimmed CSS that emulates the native behavior.
- ViewEncapsulation.None: Use global CSS without any encapsulation.

By default, a class that you've defined in the `.css` file for a component will only be available for use in that component. If you want to use it in some other component, it won't be available. Angular automatically adds these `texts` to the classes so that they are not accessible outside the component.

thoughtram.io has an amazingly enlightening article on this which you can read [here](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/06/29/shadow-dom-strategies-in-angular2.html) to understand this better.